# Check user access level with PHP

Tags: php

I've created a simple login script in php. I also want to implement a user-access level system. So when user logs in the php will check in MySQL if user is admin and if he's not it will hide some of the frontend panel options. Do you have any ideas how to hide some html parts? Or do I have to create different views for different access level? Thank you for your time

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control

Comment: Look into access control list and php and read about the different methods you can use. There are a lot of different ways to do this each with varying levels of complexity it all just depends on your needs which no one here would be able to answer but you.

Comment: Thank you for your anwsers. I don't understand how to tell to html that a certain part needs to be hidden.

Comment: Well, when I want to do this what I do is have a table to store what each user can do. Then in my application, build the HTML using php, query what the user can do, if they can see that item then i add the html elements, else I just skip it.

Comment: That's clever. I didn't know I could do this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are searching for this?

```
<?php

  //do your stuff...
  $login = true;  //or false...

?>
<p>put some html here...</p>

<?php if($login==true): ?>
<p>this html will be shown only if you are logged in...</p> 
<?php else: ?>
<p>sorry, you are not logged in</p> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Find more at
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: No I need to read the table from mysql then store it into a variable $_SESSION['user_level'] and then check in another file if the user is admin or not.